# How can I remove added points from field?

Tags: c#

I can add points in the field but I cannot remove them. This is the code I am currently using:

```
public class Vertex
{
    public Point p { get; private set; }
    public int ident {get; private set; }
    public int dist { get; set; }

    public Vertex(Point p, int ident)
    {
        this.p = p;
        this.ident = ident;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where in the code you add the point and how you think to remove it?

Comment: When you try to remove it, what error are you getting?

Comment: could i send someone program on email to see it at all?

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps use:

```
this.p = Point.Empty;
this.indent = 0;
```

Hence call your method Vertex like this:

```
Vertex(Point.Empty, 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could setup a Reset method for `p`

```
public class Vertex
{
        public Point p { get; private set; }
        public int ident {get; private set; }
        public int dist { get; set; }

        public Vertex(Point p, int ident)
        {
            this.p = p;
            this.ident = ident;
        }

        public void Reset() { p = new Point(); }
}
```

Comment: `Point` is a struct, and as such can't be `null`.

Comment: @Seervy - That's assuming he is using the .NET defined Point (which he has not specified).  Not hard to fix.

Comment: What is the syntax `p = new p();`?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan - All structs have an implicit default constructor.  `new p()` is a call to said constructor to overwrite the variable.

Comment: Are you sure? Check your syntax.

Comment: Oh...lol.  NM I updated it.  Installing VS 2012 right now so can't verify my code easily.

Comment: could i send someone program on email to see it at all?